# Android Studio: List all calls which requires SDK level above the project minimum level

Tags: android, ide, android-studio

I have been developing an android application. Previously the decided minimum level was 4.0 but now it's 2.3.3. So there are certain call in my project which requires SDK level 14 and hence app is crashing in 2.3.3. I'm using Android Studio IDE. Is there a way in Android studio to list down all such calls. Need this to estimate the conversion time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set your minSdkVersion to 10 (2.3.3) and do a full build:

`./gradlew clean build`

Next look at the report generated by Lint. It will tell you where you have made API calls that are not supported on API level 10.

Comment: Where to look for  the 'report generated by Lint'?

Comment: The build will print out the location of the report file.

Ran lint on variant release: 6 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 6 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:/home/litrik/git/SampleProject/app/build/outputs/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to /home/litrik/git/SampleProject/app/build/outputs/lint-results.xml

Comment: Couldn't check again. Will be testing soon.